# Imagemagick 7 on AWS Centos7 cannot find library

Tags: imagemagick, centos7

I have a setup provided by my work, with limited ability to change the configuration. We have a non-standard configuration which includes ImageMagick 7 installed in special directory. It works, I can run `identify` and `convert` without a problem provided I use the special path to the directory.

It's installed in a package which included lots of other things. The entire package is set up to be installed on customer machines. It's been working for years, but one customer wants to install it on an AWS Centos7 machine and it mostly works, except for Imagemagick.

The problem arises when calling `identify` or `convert` when we get this error

```
 {package_name_removed}/vendor/imagemagick/CentOS6/bin/identify: error while loading 
     shared libraries: libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such 
    file or directory
```

`libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.5` exists in the `CentOS7/lib` directory.

I can solve this problem by using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. But that requires changing the package installation, and that can't be done. We cannot see why this works on Centos7 on non-AWS stacks without having the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Somehow the executable binary is able to find `libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.5` without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and that "somehow" isn't working in the AWS Centos7

I cannot recompile ImageMagick with different flags, I cannot add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I cannot create symlinks, because all those things require changes to our package and that's not possible.

If I install ImageMagick in a clean AWS Centos7 image then it works perfectly.

I need to know what might be different on the AWS Centos7 image that might prevent Imagemagick finding the `libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.5` file without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` being set.

I know it's a long shot but someone somewhere might have a comment that could lead to an answer

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Found our problem. When packaging up all the component parts ImageMagick was compiled with hard coded paths to the libraries. Which meant the paths started with `/home/user_logged_in_when_compiling_imagemagick`. On a customer's server the package was installed with a different home directory and therefore failed.

Duhhh!